# How do I split an array using nil as delimitor?

Tags: ruby

I'm searching a method for converting:

```
[1,2,3,nil,4,5,nil,6,7,8,9]
```

into:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]
```

Is there a built-in way to do that in Ruby?

Comment: No. :-) Are you interested in the most straightforward, Ruby-like way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
array = [1,2,3,nil,4,5,nil,6,7,8,9]
array.inject([[]]) do |result, number|
  number ? result.last << number : result << []
  result
end

#=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Explanation time :-)

- inject starts with an array containing an empty array
- for each element, it checks if it's nil
- if it isn't, it appends the current number to the previous array
- if it is, it creates a new empty array
- all this while updating result, which is an array of arrays

-- EDIT --

Checking David's reply I checked Rails implementation of this:

```
def split(value = nil)
  using_block = block_given?

  inject([[]]) do |results, element|
    if (using_block && yield(element)) || (value == element)
      results << []
    else
      results.last << element
    end

    results
  end
end
```

If you skip the block implementation, it has the exact same structure of my code. Yay! :)

Comment: For what it's worth, this pretty much matches the Rails implementation of array#split, modulo the additional Rails flexibility, at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ccf9577aee86ce1f766c5e8854e0c285dc38f8ac/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/grouping.rb#L87

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, I just noticed the same thing and I felt proud for a second!

Comment: @JuLiu: As indeed you should, for that a second and many more!  Well done!

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug or a feature, but a leading or trailing `nil` in the array will result in a leading or trailing empty subarray with this approach.

Comment: Yeah, I've though about that while coding, and I got myself convinced that it is a feature: if we want to split an array with a token and this token happens at the beginning of the array, then we have found the first sequence, which is sadly an empty sequence. I think it makes sense! Moreover, it is kinda the same approach as String#split: `"0abc0cdc".split("0") => ["", "abc", "cdc"]`

Answer (score 6):

I'd use:

```
[1,2,3,nil,4,5,nil,6,7,8,9].slice_before{ |e| e.nil? }.map(&:compact)
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

[`slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) is really powerful when you want to break an array into chunks, either by searching for a repeating pattern by passing in a regex, or something you can compute via the block. It's much too powerful to summarize right here so take time to read the documentation and play with the examples.

Comment: Good one (+1). And... compact. :)

Comment: `slice_before` is one of those little known methods in Ruby that I didn't notice for a while, then did a palm-to-face move. It's turned out to be incredibly useful for a lot of text processing. If you have a file of repeating blocks it makes it easy to split it into arrays of chunks.

Answer (score 2):

```
[1,2,3,nil,4,5,nil,6,7,8,9].split(nil)
```

Whoops `array#split` is a Rails [method](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/split)

Comment: undefined method `split' for [1, 2, 3, nil, 4, 5, nil, 6, 7, 8, 9]:Array

Comment: Arrays are not strings :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found kind of an interesting one. There's probably a way to shorten it:

```
[1,2,3,nil,4,5,nil,6,7,8,9].chunk {|e| e.nil?}.select {|e| not e[0]}.flatten(1).delete_if {|e| not e}
```

Comment: Using `chunk` is a good idea, but it's better to use `nil` and anything else instead of `true` and `false`. For example: `[1,2,3,nil,4,5,nil,6,7,8,9].chunk {|e| :grouped unless e.nil?}.map(&:last)`

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune, thanks, good suggestion. I rolled with the default output of `chunk` without giving it much further thought, figuring there was probably a better way. This thread has caused me to discover a couple of cool Ruby array methods. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would join the array and then split the array.

```
a =[1,2,3,nil,4,5,nil,6,7,8,9] 

a = a.join("-").split("--")
a.map! { |a| a.split("-") }
a.map! {|e| e.map! {|f| f.to_i}}
puts a.inspect

#[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Made edits (based on comments), to make it an integer once again. Still not a good answer though.

Comment: Horrible solution, there is no reason to convert elements to strings.